# pdfMake create method Arguments are invalid

Tags: pdfmake

I had been successfully generating a pdf using pdfmake I am now getting this error and I'm not sure what has changed. Even the simple examples are throwing errors.

```
const docDefinition = {
    content: [
        {
            layout: 'lightHorizontalLines', // optional
            table: {
            // headers are automatically repeated if the table spans over multiple pages
            // you can declare how many rows should be treated as headers
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: ['*', 'auto', 100, '*'],

            body: [
                ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one'],
                ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],
                [{ text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4']
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              };

 const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
```

Results in:

```
//Argument type {content: {layout: string, table: {headerRows: number, 
widths: (string | number)[], body: (string[] | ({text: string, bold: 
boolean} | string)[])[]}}[]} is not assignable to parameter type 
TDocumentDefinitions
```

However, if I use:

```
const docDefinition = {
    content: 'Hello World'
};

const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
```

All seems well. I don't quite understand how any of the examples in the playground are working at this point. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that I am unable to explain, changing my import to this resolved my issue.

```
const pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake');
const pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts');
```

I am including `pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;` further down in my page when I am actually building out the pdf.